# Error : Her services to the masses in general and women in particular will always be remembered

Tags: exam-questions

> Her services to the masses in general and women in particular will always be remembered.

My book suggests to  add **to the** before *women* , Is it necessary ? I'm really confused because many times I have come across sentences in which clauses/prepositions/words such as **to the** etc have been used just one time before the former part of the sentence which is joined by *and* many times, just like above sentence, I am asked to use for both parts of sentences separately. Can any one drive it home to me when to to use it separately and when I can get away with just using it with former clause ?

Comment: I think for the sake of readability, it's required. Had it been *"Her services to the masses and women in particular will always be remembered,"* it would have been okay! The words 'in general' make me forget the previous part and thus you need to tell me again! :)

Comment: You could use "to women" or "women" referring to women in general, or "to the women" if a specific group of women is being referred to. More context is needed to answer this.

Comment: The grammar is fine as it is. You could change it to "... and to women ..." if you think the sentence is complicated enough that the reader will have forgotten the original "to".  It should **not** be "... and to **the** women ..." because the definite article implies that you are only referring to a predefined set of women.